# Multithreaded vs. ValueRangeProvider in a PlanningEntity

Tags: multithreading, optaplanner

We attempted to use the new "multithreaded incremental solving" feature introduced 7.9Final, by simply adding  to our .xml configuration file.

It seems that when we de-activate our ValueRangeProvider in the PlanningEntity, it works, but when we activate the ValueRangeProvider, it breaks.

- First of all: is that expected?

To solve the problem, we tried to replace the ValueRangeProvider by a ValueSelector.

Unfortunately, we found no example of this feature apart the very short intro in section 8.6.4.2. ("Filtered Entity Selection") of the docs. This was not sufficient for us to understand how to implement correctly a ValueSelector.

- Was that a good approach to solve the problem?
- If it was, do you have any pointers/hints/examples on how we could implement that?

Thanks in advance for any help

Stacktrace :

```
   "Thread-7@7390" prio=6 tid=0x28 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:135)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:187)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:157)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:70)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:191)
      at com.astree.business.planning.automaticplanning.optaplanner.testbed.gui.OptaPlannerTestBedGui.lambda$toggleSolving$1(OptaPlannerTestBedGui.java:110)
      at com.astree.business.planning.automaticplanning.optaplanner.testbed.gui.OptaPlannerTestBedGui$$Lambda$120.796893540.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"OptaPool-2-MoveThread-3@7448" prio=5 tid=0x2b nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at com.astree.business.planning.automaticplanning.optaplanner.temporalmodel.score.TemporalIncrementalScoreCalculator.afterVariableChanged(TemporalIncrementalScoreCalculator.java:86)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.incremental.IncrementalScoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(IncrementalScoreDirector.java:154)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMove.doMoveOnGenuineVariables(SwapMove.java:115)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:40)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:30)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:175)
      at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:142)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This is a clear bug, please [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER). "ValueRangeProvider per Entity" is not used often, but that's no excuse for it now working together with multithreaded solving.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your quick reply. Is there a workaround in the meantime? Is our idea to use a Value Selector feasible? If so, do you have a more complete example than the one in the documentation/examples? Our main problem is that we would like to access both the Value and the Entity on which OptaPlanner is working.

Comment: What's the stacktrace when this happens? I want to know if this is indeed related to ValueRangeProvider in Entity and not just because of [this TSP/VRP issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1238).

Comment: I forgot to mention that we use the Incremental Java Score Calculation.
Problem : The PlanningVariable associated with the entity's ValueRangeProvider is never called in AfterVariableChange / BeforeVariableChange.

Comment: The score calculation type (inc or drl) shouldn't impact this at all. Try switching to easy java (and run it for much, much longer) to verify.

Comment: The ValueSelector idea is a bad plan imo. Please create a jira with an isolated reproducer - I am confused as to what exactly is being used atm.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, Just to let you know I added both classes we are using to the Jira ticket I created. You will see we are using a very basic implementation of Optaplanner, the only issue is trying to use multithreading where a PlanningVariable is pointing to a ValueRangeProvider in our entity instead of the solution. When multithread is disabled everything works fine. I saw you started working on my ticket, don't hesitate to ask me anything if you need more info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you add a jira link here?

Comment: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1209